# Is it possible to stop tracking files in the git repo, but have them remain in all remote checkouts?

Tags: git, deployment, git-push, git-remote

I accidentally added a third-party library into my repo and pushed the changes to the live server, which is a bare repo with a post-receive hook that checks out the master branch into the webroot.

I'd like to stop tracking the files in my local repo, add them to the .gitignore and then push my changes to the live server, without deleting the files from the live server. I still need that library on the live server, just not managed by version control. I'd like to be able to make changes to the library on the live server (all best practices aside) without it being overwritten with the version from the git repo on every push.

Is this possible? I've tried it with other repos and it's always deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The .gitignore file will ignore the file completely - so it won't be tracked, and it wont be part of the repository. You can ignore changes to a tracked file using [`git-update-index`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-index.html) with the `--assume-unchanged` flag.

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <path>
```

The `--assume-unchanged` parameter allows you to make changes locally without having to check them in or push them up. This however will not keep the file from being overwritten by a checkout. To prevent that, you should instead use the following flag.

```
git update-index --skip-worktree <path>
```

Either of these will only affect the local repository. The fact that your assuming the path will remain unchanged, or that it should be skipped can not be pushed to any remote - think of it as a local config.

However, as I say so often about these sorts of thing, *the real answer* is to stop using git as a deployment tool. There are plenty of tools out there that can handle deployments with much less hassle than git. (capistrano, phing, ant, etc...)

Comment: I hear you on using an actual deployment tool, but I don't always have a choice in the matter. I'm trying to work with someone who already has it set up this way and want to be able to untrack the files without deleting them from the server, as it will break the site. Unfortunately, git update-index and adding to .gitignore doesn't help. The files are still in the repo, so the post-receive hook on the server runs git checkout master and the library is overwritten with the repo version.

Comment: Oh I think I misunderstood then. You dont want the file in your repository at all? You just want the file on your "local" machine, but untracked. Correct? If this is what your asking, I will rewrite my answer, because I misunderstood.

Comment: Btw, I totally get it that you don't always have control of the processes used on a project. I said what I did in hopes that you keep it in mind if your on the project for long term, you may want to try to influence how its done in the futire.

Comment: Right, I don't think there's a way to accomplish this, hence the question. :) I want to remove the file from the repo completely, but I don't want it deleted from the working copy of any checkouts. I basically want it turned back into an untracked file so that the next time I push local to remote, the remote repo (a bare repo with post-receive hook that runs `git checkout master`) won't lose the files that are now untracked as that will break the live site. If the files were 'always' untracked, then a checkout wouldn't disturb them, but if I git rm --cached or update-index they get deleted.

Comment: Ok, your telling me mixed things a little bit. The file in question IS in the repo correct? You want people the clone the repo, and have some generic or default version of the file. You want to make changes, but not have to push them, and when someone else makes changes that they do push, you dont want those changes overwriting yours during a pull/checkout. This is different than what I asked before, because in this scenario the file *does* exist in the git repo on the remote.

Comment: If the above is what your trying to achieve, you shoudl instead try `git update-index --skip-worktree <path>`. Try it, let me know if that works. If so I will change my answer to reflect this.

Comment: yes, the file is already in the repo. I don't want the file in the repo at all, I just don't want the remote checkout to lose the file in its working copy when I delete it as it will break the site. Will try.

Comment: `I don't want the file in the repo at all`. We keep going back and forth on this. If I clone your repository, should I get a copy of the file in question?

Comment: I think these methods above may not be working for you because the file is indexed. Try running the `--skip-worktree` method, followed by `git rm --cached <path>`

Comment: Doesn't work, the files are still deleted after pushing to the remote repo. Do I need to try to run `--skip-worktree` on the remote repo? I'm guessing that there isn't a solution to this, and I'll just have to replace the files manually. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Im confused by what you keep calling "the remote repo". I think this is why we keep going back and forth. When people talk about a remote repo, they generally are referring to the bare repository they push to and pull from. A bare means it never actually creates working versions of the files, it just holds the history - so you would never do anything "on" that repo except seting up hooks or access rules. It sounds like you are talking about a local working clone that happens to be on a remote server - like your ssh'ed into a box somewhere and working on a clone. Is this the case?

Comment: If you are ssh'ed into somewhere, working on a clone of the repo, lets not call that the remote - it being on a remote server is irrelevant. Wherever you have actual files you cloned - thats a local repo. The remote is the repo you push/pull to/from - github/bitbucket/whatever.